# Network Card Properties is disabled

Tags: windows-7, networking

I can not edit my IP address from the Network Properties panel, because the "properties" button is not active.

Is there any way to activate it?

This is what I see:
[image]

Comment: Is this your home system, or a system at work? Are you an administrator on the local computer?

Answer (score 3):

Your user account might not have the required privileges for the button to be enabled. The button requires Administrative privileges - your user account might be a limited user account, especially if it's on computer at work

Comment: my account is as Administrator. My OS is Windows 7 home premium